# Reverse chronological order of struct/results

Tags: mongodb, sorting, go, time, mgo

Just started learning goLang.

Wondering how can we sort an struct elements in reverse order in Go. Let's say, I am getting the results from database something like as:

```
var results []<someClass>
collection.C(results).Find(bson.M{"<someid>":<id_val>}).All(&results)
```

Now, I have my database objects/results available in slice `results`. How can I sort the slice `results` in reverse order on a column called time?

Comment: Are you getting the results from MongoDB?

Comment: @notionquest, Yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easiest would be to let MongoDB sort the records:

```
var results []YourType
err := sess.DB("").C("collname").Find(bson.M{"someid": "someidval"}).
    Sort("-timefield").All(&results)
```

If for some reason you can't or don't want to do this, you may utilize the [`sort`](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/) package. You need to implement [`sort.Interface`](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Interface).

For example:

```
type YourType struct {
    SomeId    string
    Timestamp time.Time
}

type ByTimestamp []YourType

func (a ByTimestamp) Len() int           { return len(a) }
func (a ByTimestamp) Swap(i, j int)      { a[i], a[j] = a[j], a[i] }
func (a ByTimestamp) Less(i, j int) bool {
    return a[i].Timestamp.After(a[j].Timestamp)
}
```

This `ByTimestamp` type is a slice of `YourType`, and it defines a reverse timestamp order because the `Less()` method uses [`Time.After()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.After) to decide if element and index `i` is less than element at index `j`.

And using it (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/UmDECyPOmA)):

```
var results []YourType

// Run your MongoDB query here

// Now sort it by Timestamp decreasing:
sort.Sort(ByTimestamp(results))
```

An alternative implementation for `Less()` would be to use [`Time.Before()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Before), but compare element at index `j` to index `i`:

```
func (a ByTimestamp) Less(i, j int) bool {
    return a[j].Timestamp.Before(a[i].Timestamp)
}
```

Try this variant on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/9GsdWnlDgf).

Comment: Yep. Thanks for the answer. I understood your intent as well.